# Access: Error on vba table deletion

Tags: vba, ms-access

We use an .mdb file which binds several external tables from another .mdb file
using

```
Dim db As Database
Dim tdef As TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdef = db.CreateTableDef(AliasTableName)
tdef.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & SourceDB
tdef.SourceTableName = SourceTableName
db.TableDefs.Append tdef
db.Close
```

where `SourceDB`, `SourceTableName` and `AliasTableName` is passed as argument.

This worked for many years but all of a sudden one of the tables crashes with the error no `3012` saying the table/object already exists. But the table is not listed.

Before binding a table `DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tablename` is called to remove old bindings. This method call now errors with no `94` Unauthorized use of Null.

Looking for a possible hidden table with the same name I activated "Show system tables" in the current database options and lo and behold there the table is. But the joy lasts only briefly, because shortly afterwards access crashes completely.

Compressing and repairing the database has no effect.

Has anybody ever experienced something similar or has an idea what to do?

Comment: Try importing everything into a fresh access db, it could be corrupt.

Comment: Since we can't see the full context of your code, you may just need to issue: db.TableDefs.Refresh
either before you attempt the append, or after your delete.